# Rails 3.1 - Using Devise/Cancan with Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, prawn

In my html.erb views I can normally use code like:

```
if current_user.role?(:label)
"do something"
end
```

I'm trying to do the same in a Prawn based PDF but am getting a "undefined local variable or method `current_user'" error.

I understand I need to explicitly include a helper in my PDF class, something like:

```
class SalesnotePdf < Prawn::Document
  include CanCan::Ability
  "do pdf layout here"
end
```

But this doesn't appear to work? Any ideas on the correct include or other approach to this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I think current_user is actually a Devise method I need to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `current_user` really is a Devise method and is available in views, helpers and controllers, but not models. A better approach would be to check the user's role in a controller and then call a specific Prawn document.

Answer (score 0):

Unless each user needs a significantly different report, you could pass view_context as one of your parameters.

Controller

```
...
format.pdf do
...
    pdf = MyPdf.new @records, reportDate, view_context
...
end
```

Then in MyPdf you pick that up...

```
def initialize(records, reportDate, view)
    super()
    @nonPagedTransactions = transactions
    @view = view
```

....

So now it is available to all your methods in MyPdf (as well as other view-context helpers), if you say...

```
@view.current_user
```